# Prize for textbook aesthetics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, noncommutative-geometry

When browsing through [Alain Connes](http://www.alainconnes.org/en/)' textbook on [Noncommutative Geometry](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf), whose illustrations must have been conceived as true works of love, I was wondering if there is a recognized prize for [aesthetically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty) pleasing textbooks in Mathematics (and/or the other sciences.)

For what it's worth, I am also very much impressed by the structural and visually beauty of textbooks by [Gilbert Strang](http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/), [Serge Lang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Lang), and [David McKay](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/) (and I sure hope this is not too "soft" a question for this forum :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Leroy P. Steele Prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leroy_P._Steele_Prize) is awarded for expository mathematical works.  I share your appreciation of aesthetic value in math literature (which many authors evidently see as unnecessary).

Comment: There's something to be said even just for quality typography. It's really a crying shame that not a few absolute classics, like von Neumann's _Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics_ and Milnor and Stasheff's _Characteristic Classes_, haven't yet been re-typeset with LaTeX---I can't believe I'm the only one who finds the old, pre-LaTeX "typewriter"-style typesetting painful on the eyes.

Comment: Yes, LaTeX output is pleasing to the eye ... but LaTeX input is quite a horrid language IMHO :)

Comment: LaTeX makes everything look the same. I've always considered Atiyah and Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* to be very classy, not just because of the content, and would hate to see it TeXified. (Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*, on the other hand,...)

Comment: Saying all LaTeX documents look the same is like saying all MS Word documents look the same.  I'm pretty sure LaTeX allows for a lot of customization but people are typically satisfied with the standards or are too lazy to change them.

Comment: @PerManne point taken, but look e.g. [here](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html): Uses heavily customized (La)TeX template to achieve look that IMO is not-the-same. Also achieves very high information density, which I tend to like too.

Comment: Side note: Mathematicians seem to be about the only kind who still refrain from overusing Powerpoint slides (good). Some publish hand-written slides (e.g. lecture notes), which can also quite beautiful and give interesting additional insights into an author's mind.